# stretch child of indented item to full width of parent

Tags: html, css, dom

A list item (`<li>`) should be able to host children (`<div class="full-width">`), that take in a certain parents width without interrupting the document flow.

- The solution should not be affected by resizing the viewport.
- It should not involve any JavaScript.

The red parts should overlap the yellow part without changing anything else:

```css
.list { background: yellow; }
.full-width { background: red; }
.list ul { padding-left: 40px; }
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Ipsum</li>
  <li>This text
    <div class="full-width">
      full width (no yellow on the left side)<br>
      and random height (in document flow)
    </div>
    continues here and does not start a new &lt;li&gt;.
  </li>
  <li>
    Lorem
    <ul>
      <li>Ipsum</li>
      <li>This text
        <div class="full-width">
          full width (no yellow on the left side)<br>
          and random height (in document flow)
        </div>
        continues here and does not start a new &lt;li&gt;.
      </li>
      <li>Lorem</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What I have tried so far:

- Applying a **negative margin** with JavaScript that is equal the left offset. This works, but I would like to achieve it without JavaScript.
- Positioning the element **absolute**. The problem is that the element would be taken out of the document flow.
- Closing the `<li>` tags and re-opening them after the div. This solution is almost perfect, but the content after the div ("continues here and does not start a new `<li>`") starts a new `<li>` tag.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A margin, equal to the reciprocal value of the offset of the current list item can be applied:

```
.list li .full-width { margin-left: -40px; }
.list li li .full-width { margin-left: -80px; }
```

```css
.list { background: yellow; }
.full-width { background: red; }
.list ul { padding-left: 40px; }
.list li .full-width { margin-left: -40px; }
.list li li .full-width { margin-left: -80px; }
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Ipsum</li>
  <li>This text
    <div class="full-width">
      full width (no yellow on the left side)<br>
      and random height (in document flow)
    </div>
    continues here and does not start a new &lt;li&gt;.
  </li>
  <li>
    Lorem
    <ul>
      <li>Ipsum</li>
      <li>This text
        <div class="full-width">
          full width (no yellow on the left side)<br>
          and random height (in document flow)
        </div>
        continues here and does not start a new &lt;li&gt;.
      </li>
      <li>Lorem</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```